# Указание DataContext для ListBox ItemSourse, который находится внутри DataGrid ячейки

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Здравствуйте.
Имеется окно WPF MVVM. В окне находится DataGrid, одна из колонок грида содержит `ListBox`, данные которой должна предоставить `ViewModel`.

```
<DataGrid Name="OperativeScheduleTable"
          Grid.Row="1"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path= OperativeSchedules}">              
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto"
                            Binding="{Binding Path=Id}"
                            Header="Id"
                            IsReadOnly="True"/> 
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Станция отправления">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Stations}" Padding="5">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Width="50" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>               
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class RailwayStationEditViewModel : Screen
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public RailwayStation RailwayStations { get; private set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Station> Stations { get; set; }  //Сюда нужно Байндится!!!




    public RailwayStationEditViewModel(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, RailwayStation railwayStation)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;

        RailwayStations = railwayStation;
        Stations = new ObservableCollection<Station>(RailwayStations.Stations.ToList());
    }
}
```

Необходимо указать скорее всего через DataContext:

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Stations, указать что коллекция находится во ViewModel}" Padding="5">
```

А сейчас поиск коллекции `Stations` осуществляется в элементе `OperativeSchedules` (байндинг `DataGrid`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дайте имя окну `Window` у которого `ViewModel` в котором находится Stations.

Дальше привязывайтесь так:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Stations, ElementName=имяОкна}"/>
```

Comment: Отлично! все работает! спасибо!

Comment: Хотел задать еще вопрос, мне нужно редактировать ячейки в dataGrid, но когда я привязываюсь напрямую к ICollection<T>, сущности доменной модели EF, возникает ошибка редактирования. и мне приходится байндится к внутренним коллекциям ViewModel инициализированных значениями ICollection<T>. Верно ли это?

Comment: @Aldmi, у модели EF, есть VM? А так лучше отдельный вопрос задать.

Comment: Ладно задам отдельно спасибо вам!

Comment: @Aldmi, пожалуйста!